# Index out of range GridViewRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The code skips on Header as expected and enters when it becomes DataRow.. then it breaks immediately on the below error every time.  Can someone please help?

Line 252:                Button _singleClickButton = (kButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

```
 protected void Grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            MonthData month = Data[e.Row.RowIndex];

            **Button _singleClickButtonNew = (Button)e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex].Controls[0];**
             string _jsSingleNew = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButtonNew, "");


                 foreach (DayData day in month.DayDatas)
                 {
                     int index = month.DayDatas.IndexOf(day) + 1;

                     SortProjectsByStartDate(day.Projects);
                     foreach (ProjectInfo project in day.Projects)
                     {
                         Button button = new Button();
                         if (day.ContainsProjectStart(project))
                         {
                             button.BackColor = Color.FromName(project.Color);
                             button.Click += btnProjectStart_Click;
                             button.CommandArgument = project.Id.ToString();
                         }
                         else if (day.ContainsProjectEnd(project))
                         {
                             button.Click += btnProjectStart_Click;
                             button.BackColor = Color.FromName(project.Color);
                             button.ToolTip = project.Name;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             button.BackColor = Color.FromName(project.Color);
                             button.Click += btnProjectStart_Click;
                             button.CommandArgument = project.Id.ToString();
                             button.ToolTip = project.Name;
                         }

                         SortProjectsByStartDate(day.Projects);
                         button.Width = 60;
                         button.Height = 15;
                         button.ToolTip = project.Name;
                         //e.Row.Cells[index].Controls.Add(button);

                         e.Row.Cells[index].ToolTip = project.Name;

                         if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
                         {
                             e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes["onmouseover"] = "showContents('" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + " " + (index - 1) + "')";
                             e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes["onmouseout"] = "hideContents()";
                             //e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "showContents('"  + (e.Row.RowIndex + 1) + "')";
                         }

                         // Add the column index as the event argument parameter  
                         string js = _jsSingleNew.Insert(_jsSingleNew.Length - 2, index.ToString());
                         // Add this javascript to the onclick Attribute of the cell  
                         e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes["onclick"] = js;
                         // Add a cursor style to the cells  
                         e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes["style"] += "cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;";
                     }

                 }
             }
```

MY grid:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Grd" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="1500px" Height="800px"
                        OnRowDataBound="Grd_RowDataBound"  OnRowCommand="Grd_RowCommand" 
                        CssClass="grid" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="MonthName" HeaderText="Month"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="1" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="2" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="3" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="4" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="5" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="6" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="7" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="8" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="9" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="10" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="11" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="12" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="13" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="14" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="15" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="16" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="17" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="18" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="19" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="20" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="21" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="22" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="23" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="24" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="25" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="26" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="27" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="28" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="29" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="30" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="31" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why are you type-casting `ButtonField` to `Button`?

Comment: I'm using this code to make a modal.  I changed the LinkButton from the link to Button.  I admit I dont know what it's doing.  http://interviews.dotnetthread.com/2009/02/making-gridview-rows-or-individual.html

Answer (score 3):

There are issues in your code

```
Button _singleClickButtonNew = (Button)e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex].Controls[0];
```

1. You are casting `ButtonField` to `Button`
2. You are accessing cell based on `RowIndex` (`e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex]`). You only have few cells and this gives `Index out of range` exception as there may be more rows than cells. Use defined cell number to get a particular cell.

If you want to use `Button`, use it in `TemplateField` as below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="header">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" Text="btn" OnClick="btn_Click"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
```

This `Button` is easy to find using `FindControl` as below,

```
Button btn = (e.Row.FindControl("btn") as Button);
if(btn != null)
{
   //add button related code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I changed (e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex]) back to 0 like the original code i found had.  How can i change linkbutton to button?

Comment: I follow you now.  But I need it to hit the OnRowCommand="Grd_RowCommand" method in my codebehind, similar to the original code: <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ColumnClick" Visible="false" />.  Is this possible from the templatefeild?

Comment: If you are using `Button` not necessary to add `OnRowCommand`, you can add `OnClick` event like normal button

Comment: Precisely.. `this.SelectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                this.SelectedColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());`

Comment: Can you post your `OnRowCommand` event? all you are doing in `OnRowCommand` you can also do in `OnClick` event of button.

Comment: I can't access that page

Comment: Edited pastebin link for you

Comment: As I can't access that page, can you tell me what is `this` referes to in `this.SelectedRowIndex`?

Comment: This is what its supposed to look like.  You click on a color within the cell (its a button) and it opens up the modal window. http://snag.gy/saXe5.jpg

Comment: Thats a lot of code, you can remove `OnClick` and can add `CommandName` for button. You can also add `CommanArument` also. Only extra thing you may need to do is to find the button.

Comment: It is a lot of code.  Thats why I'd LOVE to fix the original issue with the LinkButton and maintain that buttonfield in the asp page. Aka maintain everything, keep onrowcommand i already have and fix the Button cast and buttonfield if i can.

Comment: Can i convert the LinkButton to a Button?

Comment: No, you can't, those 2 are different

Comment: I'm going to have to rewrite the entire program.  Thanks for the help.